# Запрос для получения человека с минимальной ЗП PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

есть простейшая таблица Staff

| id | surname | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Doe | 2000 |
| 2 | Johnson | 3000 |
| 3 | Walley | 1000 |
| 4 | Ribson | 5000 |

Нужно сделать запрос который вернет фамилию и id человека с минимальной зарплатой. Пытался так

```
select id, surname from staff
where salary = min(salary);
```

Но получаю ошибку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте с подзапросом:

```
select id, surname from staff
where salary = (SELECT min(salary) FROM staff);
```

Comment: Спасибо, сработало, галочку через 8 минут)